# Tables wont join despite one to many relationship

Tags: oracle, join, oracle11g, plsqldeveloper

I am trying to join to tables in PL-SQL Developer but despite obvious one-to-many relationship the output has only three rows where the fields FED_ST_PRJ_NBR and QP_PROJECTNUMBER match. I did a right join so that all the data from SURFACING_HISTORY_REPORT would be included in the output. Here is the sql queries I am using, its pretty simple:

```
create or replace view PROJECT_NUMBERS_GROUPED as
select t.FED_ST_PRJ_NBR,t.ROUTE_NBR,t.BEG_TERMINI,
t.END_TERMINI,t.LAT,t.LNGTD 
from SITE_MANAGER t
group by t.FED_ST_PRJ_NBR,t.ROUTE_NBR,t.BEG_TERMINI,
t.END_TERMINI,t.LAT,t.LNGTD
order by t.FED_ST_PRJ_NBR
;
--create or replace view SITE_MANAGER_COMBINED AS
select distinct t.route_nbr,t.beg_termini,
t.end_termini,t.lat,t.lngtd,t.FED_ST_PRJ_NBR,s.*
from PROJECT_NUMBERS_GROUPED t right join SURFACING_HISTORY_REPORT s    
on t.fed_st_prj_nbr = s.QP_PROJECTNUMBER
order by t.route_nbr
```

To be certain, I checked that a one-to-many relationship exists between t.fed_st_prj_nbr and s.QP_PROJECTNUMBER by creating a primary key with t.fed_st_prj_nbr on another table and it worked fine.  Here are pieces of the two data sets I am trying to join. The first one is part of the PROJECT_NUMBERS_GROUPED table.

```
FED_ST_PRJ_NBR    ROUTE_NBR BEG_TERMINI END_TERMINI LAT LNGTD
AR 29148            LOCAL   0.1             472927  1112041
ARRA 0002(874)      DIST WIDE               470636  1044251
ARRA 101-1(4)2      N-101   2.34    2.43    473129  1111724
ARRA 1028(4)        U-1028  0.12    1.46    454754  1082627
ARRA 1031(11)       U-1031  1.938   2.912   454544  1083703
ARRA 1031(9)        U-1031  4.762   2.912   474405  1083703
ARRA 11-1(51)53     P-11    53.2    57.9    454005  1103302
ARRA 13-1(45)37     P-13    36.8            451141  1114044
ARRA 15(90)         N-5     0.007   1.506   480933  1141816
ARRA 15(91)         N-5     1.506   3.046   481033  1141924
ARRA 15(92)         N-5     3.046   3.994   481124  1142001
ARRA 15-2(81)125    I-15    125.5   126.2   455930  1123254
ARRA 15-4(89)240    I-15                    470514  1115740
ARRA 16(73)         LOCAL                   454032  1110107
ARRA 1806(8)        U-1806  0.0 0.7         455958  1123141
ARRA 1810(4)        U-1810  0.1 1.4         455957  1123004
ARRA 235-1(11)2     S-235   1.9 4.5         454346  1110711
ARRA 25(50)         LOCAL   0.7 1.5         463616  1115559
ARRA 260-1(5)0      S-260   0.0 3.6         482442  1153432
ARRA 27-1(9)2       P-27    2.3 6.8         455434  1043208
```

and here is part of the other dataset (just a few of the columns and rows):

```
QP_PROJECTNUMBER    QP_PROJECTNAME  QMI_NAME    QMI_ITEMNUMBER
ARRA 101-1(4)2  SMELTER AVE & 10TH ST N-GREAT FALLS PLANT MIX GR D   - COMMERCIAL TESTED    401020022
ARRA 101-1(4)2  SMELTER AVE & 10TH ST N-GREAT FALLS PLANT MIX GR D   - COMMERCIAL TESTED    401020022
ARRA 1028(4)    LOCKWOOD - SOUTHEAST    PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020022
ARRA 1028(4)    LOCKWOOD - SOUTHEAST    PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020022
ARRA 1031(11)   SHILOH ROAD CORRIDOR-BILLINGS   PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
ARRA 1031(11)   SHILOH ROAD CORRIDOR-BILLINGS   PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
ARRA 1031(11)   SHILOH ROAD CORRIDOR-BILLINGS   PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
ARRA 11-1(51)53 LIVINGSTON - NE PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 3/4 IN    401020045
ARRA 11-1(51)53 LIVINGSTON - NE PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 3/4 IN    401020045
ARRA 11-1(51)53 LIVINGSTON - NE PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 3/4 IN    401020045
ARRA 15(90) KBP - US 93 TO AIRPORT RD   PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
ARRA 15(90) KBP - US 93 TO AIRPORT RD   PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020507
ARRA 15(90) KBP - US 93 TO AIRPORT RD   PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
ARRA 15(90) KBP - US 93 TO AIRPORT RD   PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020507
ARRA 15(92) KBP - FOYS LAKE RD TO US 2  PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020507
ARRA 15(92) KBP - FOYS LAKE RD TO US 2  PLANT MIX GR D - COMMERCIAL TESTED  401020507
ARRA 15(92) KBP - FOYS LAKE RD TO US 2  PLANT MIX BIT SURF GR S - 19 MM 401080000
```

Many more than just three rows out of 1600 should have properly joined. Is this a data type problem? I also tried:

```
on t.fed_st_prj_nbr like s.QP_PROJECTNUMBER
```

and that didn't change anything. Whats wrong?

Comment: what are the datatypes of `t.fed_st_prj_nbr` and `s.QP_PROJECTNUMBER`? Are there any spaces at the beginning/end of each column? (e.g. what happens if you change the join condition to `trim(t.fed_st_prj_nbr) = s.qp_projectnumber`? You may need to add or move the trim() to the `s.qp_projectnumber` column too.

Comment: That was it! It was trim() thank you very much. I wouldn't have thought of that. Go ahead and make a post for that as an answer.

Comment: I did trim on t.fed_st_prj_nbr

Comment: Better yet, you may investigate to see why you have spaces where they aren't expected. Are they redundant (not needed)? If so, would you be better off cleaning up your data (perhaps with an UPDATE statement)? If you must use wrappers like `trim()` that will prevent the use of indexes, in addition to the overhead the functions themselves add to execution time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like you might have trailing (and/or leading) spaces in the `t.fed_st_prj_nbr` column.

Try changing the join condition to:

```
trim(t.fed_st_prj_nbr) = s.qp_projectnumber
```

Comment: ... or try cleaning up the data in the first place; needing to use `trim()` like that is less than ideal.